# using WITH Query (CTE) in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

The following CTE query is working well:

```
    ;WITH QResult AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row,
    * 
 FROM [vw_ads]
) 
SELECT 
    Co1l, Col2, 
    MAX(Row) OVER()
FROM QResult
```

what i need is to `select top(10)` from this query, I have tried the following

```
Select top (10) from With ...
```

but it's throwing the following exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

How to select aggregate function from a WITH Query?

Comment: WITH (e.g. the CTE) must *always* precede the SELECT that uses it. I'm not sure why the query with TOP was made to deviate so much from the original - just adding "top 10" at the appropriate place *without* moving anything else should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havent tried..

```
;WITH QResult AS  (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad_Date DESC) AS Row, * FROM [vw_ads] ) 
SELECT top(10)
Co1l, Col2, 
MAX(Row) OVER() FROM QResult
```

Comment: TOP 10 ordered by what? Without an ORDER BY, the output will be arbitrary and unpredictable.